# C# .NET Windows Form Not Displaying

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a System.Windows.Forms.Form in a .NET 4.0 Windows Application. When I run the application from Visual Studio 2010, the form appears in the taskbar, and is also displayed on screen, but beneath the visual studio IDE.

If I build the application, publish it, install it on another PC and run it, it still appears beneath any other windows (e.g. the Windows Explorer window I double clicked the executable in).

I don't want to have the form displayed as TopMost as this causes it to appear above all other windows outside the application, but I do want it to appear above all other windows at startup, i.e. Focused.

The BringToFront method has no affect. Does anyone know how to get this to work?

Perhaps related, but the static Main() method is in a separate program class. Moving the static Main() method to the form had no affect. The form is not selected as the startup object as it doesn't show up there unless I put the static Main method within the main form.

Please help!

Comment: have you tried to make focus on window, like this.focus, when form is initialized

Comment: Yes, I just stumbled onto that as your response arrived, Senad. Thanks! But I don't know how to mark your response as the answer...

Comment: In fact, no, calling this.Focus() in the constructor didn't work. I'm completely stumped...

Comment: Just in case anyone ever needs to know. To solve this I created a Form.Load event handler and added a this.Activate() method call to it.

Now I think about it it makes sense, and is probably standard practice for all experienced Forms application developers... :)

Comment: I will add answer then mark it :

Comment: The Main() probably shouldn't be moved.  Maybe edit your post to show the code for Main() and the code for the Form's constructor and Load event.  You shouldn't have to mess with TopMost or Focus or BringToFront, etc.

Comment: Yeah if you throw in some code, this does sounds strange as by default it should show above the IDE!

Answer (score 2):

You can focus your form once initialized

```
this.Focus();
```

I hope this helps.